# Fixed position is not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7

I have created a form with contact form 7:

```css
input[type='text'],
input[type='tel'],
input[type="email"] {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: heebo;
  color: #001a71 !important;
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border: 1px solid #001a71 !important;
  font-size: 1.563em !important;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -30px !important;
  margin-top: -28px !important;
  width: 358.713px !important;
  margin: 0 60px;
  overflow: auto position:fixed;
}

textarea {
  height: 190px;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: heebo;
  color: #001a71 !important;
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border: 1px solid #001a71 !important;
  font-size: 1.563em !important;
  margin-top: -4px !important;
  width: 322.439px !important;
  overflow: auto position:fixed;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

#button-22 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #4a5ba8;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #4a5ba8;
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  margin-left: -270px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left!important;
  overflow: auto position:fixed;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

#button-22:hover {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #4a5ba8;
  border: 1px solid #4a5ba8;
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: -270px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  float: left!important;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<div style="width:50%;padding:0 10px 0 0;float:left;">
  <label>[textarea* your-message "message"]</label>
</div>

<div style="width:50%;padding:0 10px 0 0;float:right;">
  <label>[text* your-name "name*"]</label>
</div>

<div style="width:50%;padding:0 10px 0 0;float:right;">
  <label>[text* company-name "company's name"]</label>
</div>

<div style="width:50%;padding:0 10px 0 0;float:right;">
  <label>[tel* tel-783 id:tel-783 class:tel-783 "phone*"]</label>
</div>

<div style="width:50%;padding:0 10px 0 0;float:right;">
  <label>[email email-731 id:email-731 class:email-731 "email"]</label>
</div>

<div style="width: 50px">
  <label>[submit id:button-22 class:button-22 "send"]</label>
</div>
```

I am trying to make all fields, including the send button position fixed. I want them to remain at the same place no matter what's the size of the browser or the screen resolution. After researching, I found out the transform: translatez(0) should be added so my fields won't disappear when I add the position:fixed. However, when I try different resolutions I can see that my fields move.

I have attached the entire CSS code in order to see if some attributes contradict what I am trying to achieve here.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is generated? :) Instead of the shortcode.

Comment: The plugin generates a shortcode, you can find the form at the bottom of www.mayabarber.co.il

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned position element in button22:hover 
But you should add it in
 button22
            Position : fixed;

Answer (score 0):

In fixed you need to set the properties below

1. Top
2. Right
3. Bottom
4. Left
   If you set the above property one or two can give effect to fixed position

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like adding one of these properties isn't working for some reason. That's why I went for negative margins.